# I would like to add space between buttons (maybe it is called margin) for a website

Tags: javascript, css, button, spacing

My code is made of mainly php and javascript. It also contains slight html and css.

I have tried using css style margin attribute to create the space but it did not work - maybe i have done it wrong .
I have also tried using javascript to do it but it did not work - maybe i have done it wrong.
Below is what my code looks like

```
buttons: {
            info: {
                  label: "Remove record",
                  style="margin-right:40px;",//this is what I have tried
                  style="margin-left:40px;",//this is what I have tried
                  className: "btn-info",
                  callback: function() {
                      console.log('dismiss');      
                  }
                },
            warning: {
                  label: "Confirm",
                  className: "btn-warning",
                  callback: function() {
                      console.log('confirm');
                           ...
                           ...
                           .
                           .
                           .
            main: {
                  label: "Send Message",
                  className: "btn-primary",
                  callback: function() {
                      console.log('sms');
                            ...
                            ...
                            .
                            .
                            .
            success: {
                       label: "Store",
                       className: "btn-success",
                       callback: function () {
                            console.log('save');
                           ...
                           ...
                           .
                           .
                           .
                   danger: {
                  label: "Delete",
                  className: "btn-danger",
                  callback: function() {
                      console.log('delete');
                            ...
                            ...
                            .
                            .
                            .
                               }
                           });
                  }
                },
          }
        });
```

Please tell me what I can do create the amount of spacing I want between the buttons. I am just a beginner in this field.

Comment: You should give live example of your code using snippets or sites like jsfiddle.

Comment: A live example is appreciated but not totally necessary, but you should at least add the relevant HTML and CSS. The javascript you have added is pretty irrelevant.

Comment: what do you mean by live example. Thanks Saraph.

Comment: there is nearly 0 html and css - no relevant html and css exists. Thanks max.

Comment: Honestly if you don't put more context in here I doubt someone can help you out...

Comment: please tell me what context u want and i am willing to put it in - thank john locke

Answer (score 0):

if you can create space then i have using this code may be use full for you.

```
function setSpace(amount) {
    var result = '';
    for (i = 0; i <= amount; i++) {
         result =+ '&nbsp;';
    }
    return result;
}

//Use the following in example how to use this
setSpace(3)
```

Comment: it just an example how to use this and pass on arguments

Comment: i think you have try to css may be it will be working for you.. buttons{ margin:0px 10px; }

Comment: just place in <head> section <style> buttons{ margin:0px 10px !importantl; } 100% working

Comment: i have just tried the css  by putting it in but it doesn't work now - thank you - Ravi Chauhan

Comment: Please provide other solution .Thank you.